# Как подключить модуль с GitHub в свой проект?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm

Часто встречаю на GitHub модули, в описании которых присутствуют примерно такие строки: 
`old school
Grab file from dist directory`

при этом приоритетным методом установки выделена установка посредством npm, `npm install --save cleave.js`

честно говоря, не хочется быть "old school", но и логику установки npm-пакета не понимаю, ведь по сути вся ветка с хаба скачивается в папку .node-modules моего проекта

Суть вопроса: как на примере https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js проделать путь от `npm install --save cleave.js` до инклуда необходимых файлов в html?

Answer (score 1):

Можно напрямую позависеть от проекта на гитхаб, не публикуя его в npm:

**package.json**

```
{
   ...,
   "dependencies": {
        "tiny-sdf": "git+https://github.com/strangerintheq/tiny-sdf.git#1.1.9"
   }
}
```

после решетки идет имя тега или ветки, можно хэш коммита

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно оформить/создать пакет для `npm`, для начала в корне проекта выполняешь в терминале команду:

```
npm init
```

он создает файл `package.json`, можешь руками создать, как удобнее.

Изучи, какие параметры содержит данный файл: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Далее, нужно опубликовать твой пакет в общий реестр `npm`, вот ссылка с инструкцией: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages

Если коротко, сперва создаешь юзера через консоль, затем публикуешь свой пакет.

upd: На счет `github` забыл написать, в `package.json` есть параметр отвечающий за это, вот кусок из мануала:

```
"repository":
 { 
       "type" : "git",
       "url" : "https://github.com/npm/npm.git"
 }
```

Comment: Дело в том, что `package.json` уже давным давно создан, тк использую некоторые модули. Суть проблемы в том, что я устанавливаю данный модуль, который создает свою директорию в node_modules, а далее я просто не понимаю как его(этот модуль) сконфигурировать для использования в своем проекте. Как из созданной модулем папки выдернуть нужные мне файлы и положить  в место назначения(напр. "./js/") я понимаю

Comment: ну если данный модуль дает возможность такого кастома, то логично, подключаете нужный файл пакет/файл из `node_modules` и используете его, но если такой кастом не предусмотрен, то как вы и писали, либо копировать в папку `js` :) либо делать fork проекта и перепилить то что вам нужно, ну или создать issue в проекте

Comment: может я не правильно понял суть

Comment: интересует алгоритм действий между этими 2мя этапами: https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js#installation и https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js#usage

Comment: @griff92, ну тут получается вам нужен 100% какой-нибудь сборщик (это как раз не одскульно), иначе тупо копирование (как вы и писали) либо прямо в `src` ссылаться на `node_modules` что мне кажется не хорошо